# Hive: Using RegexSerDe to define input format

Tags: regex, datatable, hive

I looked at several solutions but none of them worked before deciding to post my question here. I a trying to create a table in hive and load data in it from a csv of the form `String A, "String B"`. I tried writing the regex myself but whenever i load data, all values are NULL.

My create table command is as follows:-

```
create table tab1 (col1 string, col2 string)                    
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'     
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (                                                 
    "input.regex" = "\"([^\"]*)\",\"([^\"]*)\"$")
```

And i am loading data by the following command:-

```
load data inpath '/path/to/file.csv' into table tab1;
```

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the regular expression.Try the below code.

```
create table tab (col1 string, col2 string) ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
("input.regex" = "([^ ]*),\"([^\"]*)\".*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use[a CSV serde](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde) instead (this one knows about quote characters by default).:

```
add jar /home/hadoop/hive/lib/csv-serde-1.1.2-0.11.0-all.jar;
create table tab1 (col1 string, col2 string) 
row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde';
```